# How do I select specific vectors of a matrix to be plotted against each other (such as when using hexplom)?

Tags: r, plot, subset

Is there a quick way to code for those specific vectors? Like I only want to use every 4th column in my matrix then plot the selected columns. I'm very new to R and have absolutely no idea what I'm doing. I know how to select a single vector and how to select a certain number in a row but that doesn't really help.

Comment: It always helps if you give an example of what you're trying to do, with a little bit of data supplied. Even if you only can start your code it gives us something to work with. See this for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: This is for a microarray of gene expression for 24 samples (columns) & around 13000 genes (rows). I would like to make use the hexplom command to plot 6 of the 24 samples (not in order next to each other in the matrix) against each other to make comparisons.

Comment: How would it work for just a set of random column numbers? Say I wanted to do columns 2, 7, 9, and 16 from a matrix with 20 columns.

Comment: Ok so looking at hexplom you could do something like this. Say your dataset is called `foo`. To plot columns 2,7,9, and 16 you can do this: `hexplom(~foo[,c(2,7,9,16)])`

Comment: That worked! I had tried that before but missed the ~

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'm a biologist trying to learn coding and I have been riding the struggle bus.

Comment: If you could select my answer that would be great.

Comment: @user14353 how do I do that?

Comment: There should be a checkmark by the arrows on my answer. Just click that.

Comment: I think I got it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to extract every 4th column from a matrix you can use `seq()`.
Here's an example. I made a dummy dataset: `foo<-matrix(c(rep(c(4,3,2,7),100)),nrow=10,ncol=10)`

Then you can store the column indexes that you want from your matrix like so:

`colsyouwant<-seq(from = 4, to = ncol(foo), by = 4)`

from = whatever column you'd like to start from, in your case the 4th. Then you specify where you'd like to stop, so I used the `ncol` function to count how many columns are in the matrix. In this case my matrix isn't a multiple of 4 but it doesn't matter because `seq` stops before then. Then by=4 because you want to select every fourth column.

The `colsyouwant` now equals to `4 8`. Simply use brackets and the name of your variable to get the columns you want out. `foo[,colsyouwant]`. Here the brackets just specify what part of the matrix I want as an output, it goes [rows,columns]. Since I want all the rows I leave that spot blank and then specify the rows using the `colsyouwant` variable, or in other words `4 8`.

Comment: How would it work for just a set of random column numbers? Say I wanted to do columns 2, 7, 9, and 16 from a matrix with 20 columns.